# how to show comment in presto after creating a table?

Tags: sql, presto

I created a table like below with some comment

```
CREATE TABLE some_catalog.some_schema.tmp (
  address VARCHAR COMMENT 'address',
  name VARCHAR COMMENT 'name'
)
COMMENT 'some comment'
;
```

How could users find the comment when they make a query, `describe` does NOT show it?

```sql
>describe somme_catalog.some_schema.tmp;
presto> describe somme_catalog.somme_schema.tmp;
 Column  |  Type   | Extra | Comment 
---------+---------+-------+---------
 address | varchar |       | address 
 name    | varchar |       | name    
(2 rows)
```

Also, what is the `Extra` column for?

I'm using https://prestosql.io/

Answer (score 1):

Just write: `SHOW CREATE TABLE some_catalog.some_schema.tmp`

This will show you pretty much the same command you wrote when creating the table, so you will be able to see the comment as well.

Comment: Do you know what the "Extra" column is about in "describe" output?